# TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```
module.exports = {
    name: "dm",
    description: "DM a user in the guild",
    category: "fun",
    run: async (bot, message, args) => {
      if (!member.message.author.id === ("356440200253276163"))
        return message.channel.send("**:x: You cannot use this command as it is only for the owner of bot. :x:**");
      let user =
        message.mentions.members.first() ||
        message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
      if (!user)
        return message.channel.send(
         `**:x: You did not mention a user. :x:**`
        );
      if (!args.slice(1).join(" "))
        return message.channel.send("**:x: You did not specify your message. :x:**");
      user.user
        .send(args.slice(1).join(" "))
        .catch(() => message.channel.send("**:regional_indicator_x: That user could not be DMed! :regional_indicator_x:**"))
        .then(() => message.channel.send(`**:white_check_mark: Sent a message to ${user.user.tag} :white_check_mark:**`));
    },
  };
```

```
(node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

2020-08-08T06:14:42.414100+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.run (/app/commands/dm.js:33:34)

2020-08-08T06:14:42.414101+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Client.<anonymous> (/app/bot.js:39:21)

2020-08-08T06:14:42.414101+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Client.emit (events.js:327:22)

2020-08-08T06:14:42.414102+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at MessageCreateAction.handle (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)

2020-08-08T06:14:42.414103+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)

2020-08-08T06:14:42.414104+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:386:31)

2020-08-08T06:14:42.414104+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:436:22)

2020-08-08T06:14:42.414104+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:293:10)

2020-08-08T06:14:42.414105+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at WebSocket.onMessage (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:125:16)

2020-08-08T06:14:42.414106+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)

2020-08-08T06:14:42.414304+00:00 app[worker.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)

2020-08-08T06:14:42.414353+00:00 app[worker.1]: (node:4) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

So I'm trying to make the DM command usable by only me, the owner of the bot because I don't want people to abuse it and get my bot banned for what they did, but it gives this error. I checked discord.js.org but I couldn't find why it happened or how to fix it. I checked the permissions section. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `if (!message.member.author.id === "356440200253276163")`,

use `if (!message.author.id === "356440200253276163")`.

`message.member.author.id` is not an object, which is why it returns undefined.

Comment: The thing is it will still allow others to do it when i do it like that as well.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. This will still make sure the author id matches whichever id you want it to.